# MPI Ring Communication deadlock

Tags: c, mpi, communication, ring

While experimenting for a school mpi project wrote this and wondering why it doesn't work:
What I want to do is simply pass all points in points to the next process (process with rank processId+1) and receive the ones from the previous. Then do the same thing receiving from the one sending to in the previous iteration and sending to the next one (processId+2 and so on).
Although it executes neatly for 2 processes, when I get to run it with 4,8,.. processes, it deadlocks after the first iteration.

```
if(processId!=noProcesses-1)
    sending_to=processId+1;
else
    sending_to=0;

if(processId!=0)
    receiving_from=processId-1;
else
    receiving_from=noProcesses-1;

for(l=1;l<noProcesses;l++)
// ring communication with non-blocking methods
{
    printf("PROCESS %d: Iteration %d: sending_to=%d/receiving_from=%d\n",processId,l,sending_to,receiving_from);

    MPI_Isend(points, size*DIMS, MPI_FLOAT, sending_to, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req);
    MPI_Request_free(&req);

    MPI_Recv(query_points, size*DIMS, MPI_FLOAT, receiving_from, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

    receiving_from=sending_to;

    if(sending_to==noProcesses-1) {
        sending_to=0;
    } else {
        sending_to++;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new send message, freeing it before it completes and then call receive:

```
MPI_Isend(points, size*DIMS, MPI_FLOAT, sending_to, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req);
MPI_Request_free(&req);

MPI_Recv(query_points, size*DIMS, MPI_FLOAT, receiving_from, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

You should free the request after the message is sent:

```
MPI_Isend(points, size*DIMS, MPI_FLOAT, sending_to, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req);
MPI_Recv(query_points, size*DIMS, MPI_FLOAT, receiving_from, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
MPI_Wait(&req);
```

Comment: Simply `MPI_Wait(&req)` after `MPI_Recv()`. `MPI_Barrier()` is an overkill and does not even guarantee the message will be sent. `MPI_Request_free()` is not needed here.

Comment: Indeed, that's true. Changing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry guys, had to post it to discover what was wrong right afterwards.
Process Ids in receiving_from and  sending_to are mixed up since the second iteration.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why there is a loop in the first place but I hope your problem is fixed.